# android10: how to set Per-display focus

Tags: android

Document address:https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/multi_display/displays#focus
target:Per-display focus
Use com.android.internal.R.bool.config_perDisplayFocusEnabled to set per-display focus.
where the resource :com.android.internal.R.bool.config_perDisplayFocusEnabled  can by find.
the document don't give the path ,I unkown how to complete the operation.

Comment: Hi @Ben, did you know the way to set per-display focus? I am finding it now. Do you have any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That value is defined here:
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml?q=config_perDisplayFocusEnabled

And here for the automotive use case:

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/services/Car/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml?q=config_perDisplayFocusEnabled