# How to enable the focus for all displays

Tags: android, samsung-dex

I am finding a way (turn on/off in the setting or adb or programmable way) to enable the focus on all displays including my phone screen and external display which is showing the desktop screen or Samsung DEX.
My purpose is to avoid focus move from external display to my phone screen whenever I touch on phone screen.
I see there is some information about this on these below links but don't exactly know how to enable it.

https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/multi_display/displays#focus

[android10: how to set Per-display focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64130469/android10-how-to-set-per-display-focus)

Hope anyone can give some advices.
Thanks.